# Enter key is not prevented with event.preventDefault()

Tags: jquery, keypress

I'm trying to prevent the use of the enter key inside inputs fields. I managed to do it for the backspace key so that my window does not close but it doesn't seem to work with the enter key. Why? Could it be because I unbind the keydown function?

```
$(document).unbind('keydown').bind('keydown', this.keyPress);

keyPress: function (event)
{
    var doPrevent = false;
    var d = event.srcElement || event.target;
    if ((d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT' &&
                                                     (d.type.toUpperCase() === 'TEXT' ||
                                                         d.type.toUpperCase() === 'PASSWORD' ||
                                                         d.type.toUpperCase() === 'FILE' ||
                                                         d.type.toUpperCase() === 'EMAIL' ||
                                                         d.type.toUpperCase() === 'SEARCH' ||
                                                         d.type.toUpperCase() === 'DATE'))
                                                    || d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'TEXTAREA') {

        if (event.keyCode === 8)
            doPrevent = d.readOnly || d.disabled;
        else if (event.keyCode == 13)
            doPrevent = true;
    }
    else
        doPrevent = true;
    if (doPrevent)
        event.preventDefault();
},
```

Comment: Prevent the enter key of doing what? And since when does the backspace key have to do with closing windows?

Comment: Inputs are integrated into a window pop-up. You have severals buttons such as "Save" or "Close". When pressing enter key without focusing on those inputs, it triggers the save function.

What I'd like to do is to disable this behavior when cursor is focused on inputs.

Comment: How does the HTML look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the code is working. If my window is still closing, it's because the enter key is connected to a different function, located in the backbone.modal.js

Thanks!